# iOS: UIPasteboard setImage: fails on iOS6 and/or Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

**Update:** Added bug 12408800 on Apple's site.

---

I am copying some one or multiple UIImage to the UIPasteboard, and it's been working like gangbusters.. until my phone upgraded to iOS 6.

- Xcode 4.5 with iOS 5.1 - **OK**
- Xcode 4.4 with iOS 6.0 - **Also OK** ([according to this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/108089-uipasteboard-not-working-anymore-with-xcode-4-5-on-ios-6.html))
- Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6.0 - **FAIL**

(also tested distributing via TestFlight, for what it's worth - still fails)

Here's my code (super basic, etc):

```
// add image to clipboard
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage"];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setPersistent:YES];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:image];
```

And here is what happens when I try to paste in an MMS/iMessage window (sorry for huge screenshot; retina display..):

[image: screenshot_of_failure]

..and an example of a failure on the Messages sample app in the iOS6 simulator (see the two question marks..?):

[image: another screenshot!]

Like I said, the above code has been working for ages, so I'm sure this is something new.

Any thoughts? On the linked post, the author suggests re-compiling on an old version of Xcode - but wouldn't that cause other iOS6 libraries to stop working?

Comment: i do need the new iOS features, unfortunately.. otherwise my rotation is totally boned on iOS 6. so, for now, I removed copy/paste from my app entirely. oy vey.

Answer (score 13):

This works for me on Xcode 4.5 for my iOS 6 devices.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];        
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(@"image");
[pasteboard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: NICE. Works perfectly for me on both 5.1 and 6.0 - when copying one image. How about copying multiple images to clipboard, as in `UIPasteboard`'s `setImages:`?

Comment: Using the setImages: still seems to not work. Guess we'll have to wait for Apple to figure out what's actually wrong with Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Quickly solved a little panic when I noticed my apps weren't working in iOS6 for no reason!  Strange that this functionality changed but we didn't get any warnings or anything about it.

Comment: works fine in ios 6.0.1! i was sending a JPEG so i change the array to load position number 1

Comment: Don't use [UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0] - its dangerous to assume that Apple will not change the order one day. The docs give nothing about the order.

Comment: What would you suggest using instead if Apple were to change the order without telling anyone?

Answer (score 7):

For only one image, you should use:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

For JPEG:

```
NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:jpegData forPasteboardType:(id)kUTTypeJPEG];
```

or For PNG:

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData:pngData forPasteboardType:(id)kUTTypePNG];
```

and avoid indexing directly in UIPasteboardTypeListImage.

Comment: +1 for adding the #import, which others neglected to mention.

Comment: you can also use @"public.jpeg" instead of kUTTTypeJPEG, as its a public constant that will never change. This saves you from linking in a whole library for one constant.

Comment: in iOS8 I was having trouble with pasting into Notes application but the code above worked. With the code I'm sharing below, pasting in Messages application was working, but now both work:UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 if (image) {
  [pasteBoard setImage:image];
 }

Answer (score 1):

I sent an email about this issue to Apple Developer Technical Support and I got this reply:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support. Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that this would be best handled as a bug report.
>
> Please submit a complete bug report regarding this issue using the Bug Reporter tool at http://bugreport.apple.com.

So it is a bug for sure...

Comment: Good call; added bug 12408800 on Apple's site. Will report back with their response.

Comment: I had also opened up a Apple Developer Technical Support with this problem and then I came up with the solution I posted the other day and sent it to them. So they know about the problem already and i've also created a bug report. Wonder if i'll get my Tech Support Incident back since I answered my own question for them ;)