# UIPasteboard: image saving issue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimage, ios6, uipasteboard

I'v thought that dealing with `UIPasteboard` is easy but it turned out to be a time-consuming issue...

I want to store an `UIImage` in `UIPasteboard` and then paste this image in `iMessage`, `WhatsApp`, `Gmail`... and others.

That's my method where I use `UIPasteboard`

```
- (void) postClipboard
{
    if ([[modelView currentView] isImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [self readyImageLandscape:orientationLandscape];
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:image];
    }
}
```

It works on `iPhone 3GS 5.1`. I've tested it on `Gmail` and `WhatsApp`

Then I modified the method to

```
- (void) postClipboard
{
    if ([[modelView currentView] isImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = [self readyImageLandscape:orientationLandscape];
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:image];
        [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setPersistent:YES];
    }
}
```

Still works on `iPhone 3GS 5.1`.

But my employer says that it doesn't work on `iPhone 4S 6.0` neither in `WhatsApp` nor in any other application.

Am I doing all wrong or there should be another approach to make it work on `iPhone 4S 6.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613632/830946

Looks like that code will work with a single image, but not with multiple.

Comment: Yep. I have found a good solution with the help of your link! Thx